# Find unique elements in tuples in a python list

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

Is there a better way to do this in python, or rather: Is this a good way to do it?

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c')
y = ('d', 'e', 'f')
z = ('g', 'e', 'i')

l = [x, y, z]

s = set([e for (_, e, _) in l])
```

I looks somewhat ugly but does what i need without writing a complex "get_unique_elements_from_tuple_list" function... ;)

edit: expected value of s is set(['b','e'])

Comment: can you explain what you want using a definition instead of an example?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's fine, that's what sets are for. One thing I would change is this:

```
s = set(e[1] for e in l)
```

as it enhances readability. Note that I also turned the list comprehension into a generator expression; no need to create a temporary list.